# Check if a numeric string is palindrome in Python

Tags: python, function, palindrome

Below is my code:

```py
def check_palindrome(num):
    my_str = str(num) 
    my_list1 = list(my_str) 
    my_list2 = list(my_str)
    my_list2.reverse()
    if my_list1 == my_list2:
        return "It's palindrome"
    else:
        return "Not a palindrome"
    
print(check_palindrome(232))
print(check_palindrome(235))
```

If I execute the code in a terminal it works, but I'm not sure if is it short and nead code or not?

Comment: What is your question? And what would you like as a result form this function?

Comment: This is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def check_palindrome(num) -> bool:
    my_str = str(num)
    if my_str == my_str[::-1]:
        return True
    return False
```

EDIT even shorter (and neater): credits @mozway

```
def check_palindrome(num) -> bool:
    my_str = str(num)
    return my_str == my_str[::-1]:
```

I did not return a string but you can do that as wel:

```
if check_palindrome(num):
    print('It is a palindrome')
else:
    print('It is not a palindrome')
```

Comment: or rather `return my_str == my_str[::-1]`

Comment: yes that is better, updated my answer